# Sending list in JSON request

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am sending few 'fields' and 'lists' in JSON to Spring MVC Controller as below:

```
    var data = {
        'message' : 'Text data',
        '**listOfIds**' : '350234983, 378350950',

        'synchronizerToken' : formTokenId

};

$.ajax({
        url : 'testURL.do',
        type : 'post',
        data : data,
        cache : false,
        dataType : 'json',

        success : function (jsonResponse) {},

        error : function (error) {}
});
```

In Spring MVC controller the URL handler looks like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/testURL.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView executeTest( ListData listData) {
        ModelAndView    modelAndView    = null;
        JsonResponse    jsonResponse    = null;

        modelAndView    = executeTransaction(listData);
        } 

        return modelAndView;
    }


ListData.java

public class ListData{
    private String          message;
    private List<String>    **listOfIds** = new ArrayList<String>();   

//getter/setters
```

The issue is **listOfIds** is not being returned as list. 
It is returned as single string **'350234983, 378350950'**

Can anyone suggest if anything is wrong here or is there any better way to receive list in JSON response?

Thanks,
-Fonda

Answer (score 7):

Make listOfIds an array of strings instead of a single string.

```
'listOfIds' : ['350234983', '378350950'],
```

Comment: I tried that initially but I get this:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)

Comment: is it becuase Object definition is not correct in java:
 private List<String>    **listOfIds** = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 0):

1.)

```
Add gson jar 

import com.google.gson.Gson;//import

Gson gson = new Gson();//create instance

gson.toJson(ListData);//convert it to json
```

2.)

Define below bean return jsonView from the controller.

```
<bean name="jsonView" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView"/>
```

Controller

```
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@RequestMapping(value = "/testURL.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String executeTest(ModelMap model, ListData listData) {
    ModelAndView    modelAndView    = null;
    JsonResponse    jsonResponse    = null;
    modelAndView    = executeTransaction(listData);
    model.addAttribute("paramName", modelAndView);
    } 

    return "jsonView";
}
```

Change in ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'testURL.do',
    type : 'post',
    data : data,
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'json',

    success : function (jsonResponse) {
       var jsonValue = $.parseJSON(jsonResponse.paramName);
    },

    error : function (error) {}
});
```

viewsResolver config in mvc-servlet.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
   <property name="location">
       <value>/path/views.xml</value>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks but we are not using Gson. We are using Jackson

Comment: Point Number 2 is not related to gson, it is spring

Comment: Ok thanks so just defining this view in xml file will take care of automatic mapping? Or I need to do additional processing in controller?

Comment: @dfsfsdfsdfsdfsdf Feel free to MArk it is as answer and to click uplink if the answer satisfied you.