# Post Rest call with List of Long as parameter

Tags: java, rest

```
@Path("/submit")
public List<SaveCResponse> submitC(List<Long> ids) {

    ICService cService = CServiceBootstrap.getCService();
    List<SaveCResponse> cResponses = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Long id : ids) {
        SaveCResponse cResponse = cService.reSubmitC(id);
        cResponses.add(cResponse);
    }
    return cResponses;

}
```

How to call the above method using postman. I mean how to pass list of IDs ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can just send them as an array in your JSON object. Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099167/sending-list-in-json-request

Comment: passed data as 

'ids' : [123]

got a error message saying : Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@1d5c835; line: 1, column: 2] @DaveCat

Comment: Broseph, that does not look like valid JSON to me. Try: {
 "ids": "[123]"
}  See if that does any better? @SVK

Comment: Try `/submit?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3`

Comment: @DaveCat, I tried that as well. I am seeing the same error.

Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@55e0dbf0; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko, No Luck. I am seeing Bad Request error.

Comment: @SVK Something sounds fishy about this. I did Google the error you posted and it lead me to someone having a similar problem. Their problem was basically like I was thinking in your case ( their JSON was jacked up because they were trying to pass in a collection). I'd say take a look there and see if you can emulate the solution to their problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837856/can-not-deserialize-instance-of-java-util-arraylist-out-of-start-object-token